# Integration test failing when trying to render a global component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

i've been writing tests for some time. Today I stumbled upon an interesting issue.
I have created a global Modal (Dialog) component `<GeneralModal />` that is rendered in the **App root**:.

I have various clickhandlers throughout the application that trigger a redux state update and depending on the state this component will render and show from the App root.

The test that is failing (returns null instead of the expected outcome) looks as follows:

```
test('open general modal', async () => {
    render(<ItemsOverview />);
    const [getRow] = await screen.findAllByTestId('table-row');

    const testBtn = within(getRow).getByRole('button', {
      name: /edit/i
    });
    userEvent.click(tamperBtn);
  
    await waitFor(()=> {
      expect(screen.queryByRole('dialog')).toBeInTheDocument();
    }, {timeout: 10000})
 });
```

it succeeds when I insert the `<GeneralModal />` into the `<ItemsOverview />` instead of the **app root**, fails otherwise.

I was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction (Am I doing something wrong?) on how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I found the issue.
When using redux and context etc, you need to wrap the render function with it and pass the rendered component as {children}

I forgot to add  in this case to the wrapper, so of course it will not work!

```
  const AllTheProviders = ({ children }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        {children}
      </ConnectedRouter>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  </Provider>
);
```